# How do I install Groove from the app cache

Tags: windows-10, groove-music

Groove music player has been discontinued and is no longer available from the app store. In 2023 Microsoft issued an update that automatically removed it from users machines and replaced it with the new Windows Media player.

The update left the unbundled libraries used to install Groove in the Windows App Cache rather than deleting them.

Apps that are stored in the app cache cannot be installed by double clicking on them, as they exist in the form of dynamic link libraries that must be registered with the OS, rather than as a self extracting executable that can be run directly.

Under normal circumstances, this can be done through the app store, but in conjunction with uninstalling Groove from user's machines Microsoft also removed Groove from the app store, meaning that the libraries must be manually registered with windows.

This is can be done through a shell script or by entering the appropriate command into the windows command line interface.

What is the correct command\series of commands, to register the unbundled version of Groove stored in the app cache with Windows 10?

This is not a question about how to download Groove from an online repository, or a request for alternatives to Groove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145228/discussion-between-aaargh-zombies-and-gantendo).

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate the exact names of the files that eist on your machine. This will determine if you have the necessary files to install the application or if the APPX package must be downloaded from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the new Media Player.

Go to https://store.rg-adguard.net

Ensure that the first drop-down box in the website has URL (link) selected.

Enter "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/groove-music/9wzdncrfj3pt" as the search term.

The second drop-down box can stay as "RP" but doesn't actually matter which option you select as the result appears on all of them and then press the tick button.

Search for "Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.21102.11411.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.AppxBundle" and download that file. (can use CTRL+F to find it)

Click on the file you downloaded and you'll see an install prompt that asks you to install the program.

Install the program and open it. Voila back to the old Groove Music. :)

Comment: I'm afraid that while this answer would allow someone to install groove it does not answer the questions because it requires a package to be downloaded fiom an unofficial archive when the question specifies installation from the app cache.

Comment: adguard does actually links back to MS's own servers - it is just a front end to things you can't find that easily for various reasons

Comment: OK, but I'm looking for something a little more specific using what's already on a computer

Comment: @Gantendo, i asked a very specific question, I communicated exactly what I wanted. If I wanted to install this another way I'd have asked a less specific question. People second guessing what I mean is unhelpful as it creates thread drift.